# Did vader know that his step family was slaughtered by his storm troopers?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode IV we see the remnants of Luke's aunt and uncle who are really his father (Vader's) step-family.

[image]

**Does Vader know his stormtroopers shot them up?** Did he authorize it? If he found out after the fact how did he react? Looking for current Disney cannon answer if possible, EU expanded universe as an after thought.

Comment: Yeah, that question is closely related, and the top answer shows that Vader definitely knew.